# Configure WCF kind="webHttpEndpoint" via code

Tags: wcf, rest, configuration

I have a WCF service, which implements interface `PosData.ISampleService` in class `PosData.SampleService`. The service is self hosted and the start up code looks like this:

```
ServiceHost serviceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(SampleService), new Uri("http://localhost:8080/sample"));
serviceHost.Open();
Console.WriteLine("Service started.");
Console.ReadLine();
```

The app.config contains the following lines:

```
<services>
  <service name="PosData.SampleService">
    <endpoint address="http://localhost:8080/sample" contract="PosData.ISampleService" kind="webHttpEndpoint"/>
  </service>
</services>
```

I would like to get rid of the App.config configuration, but I have no idea how to configure `webHttpEndpoint` via code. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use WebServiceHost instead of ServiceHost.